# where does the main.cpp moved to in recent versions?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, source-code

I was reading this [article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_1):_Overview) about bitcoin-core. It is an explanation of bitcoin-core source code version 0.3, and it described a file named main.cpp. In the recent versions this file does not exist (or at least I couldn't find it). And based on the explanations this file managed the main process of the program:

> main.h declares some key global variables (mapBlockIndex, chainActive,
> mempool, etc), constants, and functions. main.cpp is the program's
> longest source file (5,237 lines). main.cpp has most of the key
> functions for managing the blockchain, such as connecting,
> disconnecting, validating and storing blocks; identifying a certain
> block as the tip of the longest chain; and so forth. The "entry point"
> for most of the code is ProcessMessages (which listens for a signal
> from the message-handling thread.). Some of the code is run during
> initialization, called directly from init.cpp. Key dependencies: net.h

For the purpose of studying the source code I want to know where this file is moved, and if the name is changed what's the new name of the file?

I've searched for `ProcessMessages` in the whole source code and found that it was defined in the `net_processing.cpp`, does this file is the newer version of `main.cpp`?

I'm using version 23.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main.cpp` was primarily split into `net_processing.cpp` and `validation.cpp`. However, over the years, parts of `main.cpp` were moved out of it and into many other files.